# Load NSArray saved to file as NSString because I have NSNull values

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

So I have a NSMutableArray of objects I need to save to a file.  Saving it with `writeToFile` method will not work because I have NSNull values which are not allowed in the .plist format that this method generates.

So I am saving my file to disk by saving it as a NSString:

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",orders];
[content writeToFile:ordersFilePath atomically:NO];
```

Which generates a file like this:

```
(
        {
        ZBILLINGADDRESS1 = "";
        ZBILLINGADDRESS2 = "";
        ZBILLINGCITY = "";
        ZBILLINGCOUNTRY = "";
        ZBILLINGSTATE = "";
        ZBILLINGZIP = "";
        ZCANCELDATE = "<null>";
        ZCATALOGCODE = "";
        ZCATALOGNAME = "";
        ZCONTACTEMAIL = "";
        ZCONTACTFAX = "";
        ZCONTACTNAME = " ";
        ZCONTACTPHONE = "";
        ZCONTAINERCUBES = 0;
        ZCONTAINERNAME = "";
        ZCURRENCYCODE = "<null>";
        ZCUSTOMERID = 0;
        ZCUSTOMERNAME = "Dupe offline Test";
        ZCUSTOMERNUMBER = 1297145;
        ZDISCOUNT = 0;
        ZDONOTSHIPBEFORE = "<null>";
        ZEXPORTDATE = "-63113886238";
        ZEXPORTED = 1;
        ZFOB = "";
        ZFREIGHTTERM = "";
        ZISCONTAINER = 0;
        ZISDEFAULT = 0;
        ZISDELETED = 0;
        ZISPLACED = 0;
        ZMANUFACTURERID = 18;
        ZMARKETNAME = "";
        ZNOTES = "last second note";
        ZORDERDATE = 372571200;
        ZORDERGUID = "5650d30a-9316-436a-87e9-1e0ead3af8d7";
        ZORDERID = 84340;
        ZORDERSTATUS = Accept;
        ZORDERTOTAL = 200;
        ZORDERTYPE = "";
        ZORIGIN = "";
        ZPONUMBER = 3;
        ZPRICELEVEL = 2;
        ZREPNUMBER = 1;
        ZSALESREPID = 235;
        ZSHIPDATE = 373176000;
        ZSHIPPINGTOTAL = 0;
        ZSHIPTOADDRESS1 = "";
        ZSHIPTOADDRESS2 = "";
        ZSHIPTOCITY = "";
        ZSHIPTOCOMPANYNAME = "";
        ZSHIPTOCONTACTEMAIL = "";
        ZSHIPTOCONTACTNAME = "";
        ZSHIPTOCONTACTPHONE = "";
        ZSHIPTOCOUNTRY = "";
        ZSHIPTOFAX = "";
        ZSHIPTOSTATE = "";
        ZSHIPTOZIP = "";
        ZSHIPVIA = "";
        ZSOURCE = ipad;
        ZSUBTOTAL = 200;
        ZTAXRATE = 0;
        ZTAXTOTAL = 0;
        ZTERMS = "";
        ZWRITTENBYNAME = "";
        ZWRITTENFORNAME = "";
        ZWRITTENFORREPNUMBER = "";
        ZWRITTENFORREPNUMBER1 = "<null>";
        "Z_ENT" = 17;
        "Z_OPT" = 5;
        "Z_PK" = 450;
    }
)
```

problem is when I try and reload this as an NSArray I get a null value:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:ordersFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSArray *loadedOrders = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str];
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use NSKeyed(Un)Archiver.  The risk of corruption from UTF8 encoding is too high.

Comment: you lost me in this, can you explain?

Comment: Save/restore it as JSON.  JSON will handle the NSNull object just fine.

Comment: if you print `loadedOrders` to the console, what is the output? Normally you can not write `[NSNull null]` to a file. Is it `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *loadedOrders = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str];
```

initWithContentsOfFile takes path as string. In your case it is not path but content itself.

Comment: But the problem remains with `[NSNull null]`.

Answer (score 1):

What I see is that your string is actually a description of `CoreData's` `NSManagedObject` (orders array). So you can save your string to a file, but you can't recreate the same object from this file. This is just the result of the `-description` method on your `NSManagedObject`. You must implement custom logic of saving your object's data (else where, not your `CoreData's` persistent store, and a logic that will load that data, by inserting it in a `NSManagedObjectContext`) if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",orders]` just gives you the result of calling [orders description] which is just for debugging not for archiving it.

You could just call writeToFile:atomically: on your `orders` array and then do `[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]` to read it back out, there is one caveat:

> If the array’s contents are all property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects), the file written by this method can be used to initialize a new array with the class method arrayWithContentsOfFile: or the instance method initWithContentsOfFile:. This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.

so the objects in the array must all be NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary classes in order for this to work.